# Receive parse push notification and save on database and display on UITableView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, push-notification

I am new in iOS programming and I want to **handle push notification** to received it as a notification then i want to save it to **database and display in table view** how can I do that I try to handler it but I failed to do that can any one suggest any solution for that.
**another problem i have log in page** I want when program start **check database if find accounts log in** with  the user in **ns user default** **i made the method** that return the number of the accounts all I need to make condition if account ==0 goto login page else open on tab bar menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Parse.com Docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide) navigate to cache. This is your answer. I'm assuming you know how to retrieve Parse data via a PFObject and Display it to a table already. It's the same, but instead from cache.